# Parsing error with DOM classes

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying parse an XML file that looks like the following:

```
<body copyright="All data copyright CyRide 2015.">
<predictions agencyTitle="CyRide" routeTitle="1 Red West" routeTag="1W" stopTitle="Lincoln Way at Beach Ave." stopTag="1171">
<direction title="Ames Middle School via Lincoln Way">
<prediction epochTime="1422418088355" seconds="726" minutes="12" isDeparture="false" dirTag="1W_0_var2" vehicle="420" block="2004" tripTag="21181"/>
<prediction epochTime="1422420333656" seconds="2972" minutes="49" isDeparture="false" affectedByLayover="true" dirTag="1W_0_var0" vehicle="109" block="2006" tripTag="21183"/>
</direction>
</predictions>
<predictions agencyTitle="CyRide" routeTitle="3 Blue North" routeTag="3N" stopTitle="Lincoln Way at Beach Ave." stopTag="1171">
<direction title="Mall via Schilletter">
<prediction epochTime="1422417711646" seconds="350" minutes="5" isDeparture="false" dirTag="3N_1_var0" vehicle="109" block="2006" tripTag="23094"/>
<prediction epochTime="1422419941342" seconds="2579" minutes="42" isDeparture="false" affectedByLayover="true" dirTag="3N_1_var1" vehicle="189" block="2020" tripTag="23096"/>
<prediction epochTime="1422422103244" seconds="4741" minutes="79" isDeparture="false" affectedByLayover="true" dirTag="3N_1_var0" vehicle="183" block="2021" tripTag="23098"/>
</direction>
</predictions>
<predictions agencyTitle="CyRide" routeTitle="A West" routeTag="AW" stopTitle="Lincoln Way at Beach Ave." stopTag="1171" dirTitleBecauseNoPredictions="West Ames/Campustown"></predictions>
<predictions agencyTitle="CyRide" routeTitle="1B Red East" routeTag="1B" stopTitle="Lincoln Way at Beach Ave." stopTag="1171" dirTitleBecauseNoPredictions="Lincoln Way & Beach"></predictions>
</body>
```

Here is my parsing code:

```
URL url = new URL(m_url);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(conn.getInputStream());
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
01-28 09:42:23.145: E/Error:(2567): expected: /HR read: body (position:END_TAG </body>@1:1109 in java.io.StringReader@429c8958)
```

I think this is because the XML is not technically "well-formed".  Is there any way I can fix this, or do I need to find a new parser?

Comment: Your phrase "is not technically well-formed" suggests you're thinking of this as a trivial technicality. It's not, it's fundamental. XML that isn't well-formed is about as useful as Java code that won't compile. In fact, it's not really XML at all.

Comment: It seems to be valid XML except for the missing document type header

Comment: No, it's got an unescaped ampersand in the text content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem I can see is the `&` (ampersand) character in the last `<predictions>`element. If you can, change that to:

```
<predictions agencyTitle="CyRide" routeTitle="1B Red East"
routeTag="1B" stopTitle="Lincoln Way at Beach Ave." 
stopTag="1171" dirTitleBecauseNoPredictions="Lincoln Way &amp; Beach">
</predictions>
```

If you cannot change this, you can try either [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/) or [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I ended up using Android's built-in pull parser which worked fine.  This answer correctly answered my question however. Thanks!

Comment: Does that parser accept the `&` character unchanged?

Comment: I don't know if that was the problem, or if it was the missing doctype.

Comment: No, doctype isn't required, but a single `&` really makes it "invalid XML". Did you change the `&` to `&amp;`  or not?

Comment: When I looked at the XML string it was attempting to parse, the ampfersand was escaped